# Display product custom field in listing page in shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I created a custom field and assigned it to the products and I want to display that custom field value on the listing page. On the description.html.twig page, I add this below variable and the value is showing on the detail page.

```
{{ page.product.translated.customFields.custom_events_dates }}
```

The same variable I placed on the box-standard.html.twig, but the value is not showing.

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/product/card/box-standard.html.twig' %}

{% block component_product_box_info %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <div class="test">
        <p>{{ page.product.translated.customFields.custom_events_dates }}</p>
    </div>    
{% endblock %}
```

How can I display the custom field value on the listing page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `product.translated` without the `page`. The page object only contains the product data on a product detail page, on listing pages it is not set.